# jQuery: Get first element of type in top UL in a nested list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a nested list like this:

```
<ul class="list">

    <li class="list_item_type_1">
        <ul class="list">
            <li class="list_item_type_2">Unnested item</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="list_item_type_2">Unnested item</li>

</ul>
```

With jQuery I want to add a list item before all `.list_item_type_2` in the first `.list`.

I write it like this:

```
$('.list:first').find('li.list_item_type_2:first').before('<li class="list_item_type_1">Nested list (...)</li>');
```

This won't work as intended because the script finds the first `.list_item_type_2` in the **second** `.list` and appends the new code there instead.

How can I keep the search in the first `ul` and prevent it from entering underlying `ul` elements?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try to combine the selector in one expression ?

```
$('.list:first > LI.list_item_type_2:first').before('<li class="list_item_type_1">Nested list (...)</li>');
```

The `>` selector does only match the direct children, [as explained in the doc](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/child#parentchild).

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I'd advise constructing HTML that way. Use jQuery to assemble the HTML. It takes care of escaping and all those other useful things:

```
$("<li></li>").addClass("list_item_type_1")
  .text("Nested list (...)")
  .prependTo("ul.list:first > li.list_item_type:first");
```

Also, always use a tag selector ("ul.list") over a naked class selector (".list") where possible. It's **much** faster on most browsers.

Comment: Too slow...And I also like this, as it is, as you say, a better way of constructing the HTML using jQuery. +1

Answer (score 2):

You were so close!

Instead of `find()`, which searches all descendants, use `children()`, which only searches children.

Test: http://jquery.nodnod.net/cases/723/run